# How do I install the appinventor Extension Package

Tags: app-inventor

I need to install some extensions on appinventor, but I don't know how to find them and install them.

I tried looking on the official website, but couldn't find it, or maybe I didn't find it, I wish there was a way to install the extension pack I needed

Answer (score 0):

Extensions are provided by independent extension developers.

To find an extension, search in the [App Inventor community](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/) or in the extensions directory at https://puravidaapps.com/extensions.php

See the [App Inventor Extensions document](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/extensions.html) about how to use an App Inventor Extension.

Taifun